# Change the border of a CircleImageView in a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal RecyclerView that shows images for selection of a "profile" image.

[image]

I'm using CircleImageView to leave the images with rounded corners, this library makes it possible to place a border on each image.

**Note a RecyclerViewItemLayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
       android:id="@+id/avatar_select"
       android:paddingTop="5dp"
       android:layout_width="80dp"
       android:layout_height="80dp"
       android:padding="5dp"
       app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"
       app:civ_border_width="3dp"
       android:src="@drawable/avatar1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When an item is clicked, the CircleImageView border should match the color of the ColorAsset, and when a new item is clicked (as if the user changed his or her opinion about the "profile" photo and wanted another), the new item should receive the border and the old selection should return to ColorPrimary.

**Note a RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
public class AvatarAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AvatarAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Avatar> mdata;


public AvatarAdapter(Context mContext, List<Avatar> mdata) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mdata = mdata;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.escolhe_avatar,parent,false);
    final MyViewHolder vHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    return vHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.image.setImageResource(mdata.get(position).getImage());

    holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    holder.image.setBorderColor(R.color.colorAccent);
                }
            });
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mdata.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private CircleImageView image;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        image = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatar_select);

    }
}
```

}

[image]

I already broke my head, I researched but I could not reach a solution, can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking advantage of a logic from a previous answer, I thought that with each click, I should update all the items execto the one that receive the edge of ColorAccent.

**Veja a minha classe onBindViewClass do meu RecyclerViewAdapter.class**

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder,  final int position) {

    holder.image.setImageResource(mdata.get(position).getImage());
    holder.image.setBorderColor(getColor(mContext, R.color.colorPrimary));

    holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.image.setBorderColor(getColor(mContext, R.color.colorAccent));

            for (int i=0; i <= mdata.size(); i++){
                if (i != position){
                    notifyItemChanged(i, null);
                }

            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly what you want to do this should work

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.image.setImageResource(mdata.get(position).getImage());
        holder.image.setBorderColor(R.color.colorPrimary);

        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        holder.image.setBorderColor(R.color.colorAccent);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: This is not working because by running notifyDataSetChanged () you are updating all items.

Comment: i thought that's what you wanted can you clarify more what you want to do?

Comment: It was exactly that, however its code when using notifyDataSetChanged (), arrow the border of all items like ColorPrimary, not leaving a highlighted, I managed to solve and posted the solution here, take a look.

Comment: happy that you found a solution. if you found my answer helpful feel free to up vote :D thanks again.